# как передать значения из формы в класс и наоборот

Tags: c#, классы

я хочу передать значения textbox из Form1 в Class, а оттуда в Form2

Form1 вот этот textbox Логин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в этот Class Данные :

```
class Данные
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string imageurl { get; set; }
}
```

а данные из этого класса в форму Dashboard, чтобы значение Label1 был текст введенный в textbox'e

Comment: тут уже было много подобных вопросов, воспользуйтесь поиском.